# Get queryset from filter params

Tags: django, django-models

I need to filter querySet based on my request.GET URL which will have field name and value.

My Models:

```
class AnimalType(Basemodel):  
    name = models.CharField()  
    type = models.ForeignKey(Type) 

class SubAnimalType(Basemodel):  
    name = models.CharField()  
    animaltype = models.ForeignKey(AnimalType) 

class Location(Basemodel):  
    name = models.CharField()  
    country = models.CharField()  

class Animal(Basemodel):  
    name = models.CharField()  
    typeofanimal = models.ForeignKey(SubAnimalType)  
    location = models.ForeignKey(location)
```

I will get url like `"/search/?typeofanimal__animaltype__type__icontains=foo&location__country__iexact=in&food__icontains=hoo"`

Now I need a generic function which takes args Animal model & filter params as follows and should return filtered querset.

```
get_filter_from_filter_params(querySet, filter_params):  
    # logic goes here which should filter fields (i.e typeofanimal  & location ) which are all belongs/related(fk) of the querySet 
    #And should omit the model fields which not belongs to this model(i.e food field)
    return filtered query set # querySet.filter(typeofanimal__animaltype__type__icontains=foo,location__country__iexact=in)
```

I will call above method like,

```
SearchForm(request):   
    q = Animal.objects.all()  
    get_filter_from_filter_params(q, request.GET)
```

I hope I have shared enough information. I tired with model._meta.get_field(name) which supports only local field and not considering FK fields.

I like to have this function as generic, so that i can use this func for different models.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

```
Animal.objects.filter(**request.GET)
```

Comment: Here request.GET also carry param "food__icontains" which is not belongs to Animal class. So error will arise  **Cannot resolve keyword "food" into field**

Comment: Even though there isn't a security issue per se, it's still not a good idea to send use parameters as is from the request.